How do you find the current of corona discharge?
Is there a formula, or any material which would inform me of how to find the current on a cathode inciting the corona effect?

The current is strongly dependent on the applied voltage in completely nonlinear ways. The usual approach is to insert a high-valued resistor in series with the corona electrode and measure the voltage drop across it. This resistor also limits current, preventing the corona from degenerating into a power arc.

For terminal voltage control (e.g. on a Van de Graaff) the standard circuit uses a triode (vacuum tube). See "Grid-Controlled Corona, R. M. Ashby and A. O. Hanson, Review of Scientific Instruments 13, 128 (1942); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1769991 - the same circuit is still in use more than 80 years on.
